# CredentialsProvider: reliable way to check if requested credentials are for a proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to install a `CredentialsProvider` on my `AbstractHttpClient` which delegates to the `java.net.Authenticator`.
When requesting credentials from the `Authenticator`, one has to specify the `Authenticator.RequestorType`.

My `Authenticator` contains the following logic:

```
if ( requestorType == RequestorType.PROXY ){
  //retrieve credentials from some configuration
} else{
  //pop up a dialog and ask the user for credentials
}
```

This works fine for connections made through the standard `java.net` classes.

I cannot find how I can determine the correct `RequestorType` in my `CredentialsProvider`. Looking at the source code of the [`SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider`](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider.java), they cannot do this either and just request the credentials twice:

```
PasswordAuthentication systemcreds = 
  getSystemCreds(authscope, RequestorType.SERVER);

if (systemcreds == null) {
    systemcreds = getSystemCreds(authscope, RequestorType.PROXY);
```

This means that when a connecting is made through a proxy, my `Authenticator` shows up a dialog asking for proxy credentials, instead of retrieving them from a file.

*Is there a reliable way available to determine in a `CredentialsProvider` whether the credentials are requested for a proxy or not ?*

The best I could come up with is trying to re-construct the URI from the `AuthScope` and querying the `ProxySelector` myself. But I doubt my `Authscope` to `URI` conversion is bug-free.

```
RequestorType[] requestorTypes = new RequestorType[]{
    RequestorType.SERVER,
    RequestorType.PROXY
};

ProxySelector defaultProxySelector = ProxySelector.getDefault();
if ( defaultProxySelector != null ){
  try{
    //Hmm, that sounds very dodgy but the AuthScope does not contain any extra information
    URI httpURI = URI.create("http://" + aAuthScope.getHost() + ":" + aAuthScope.getPort());
    URI httpsURI = URI.create("https://" + aAuthScope.getHost() + ":" + aAuthScope.getPort());

    List<Proxy> proxies = new ArrayList<>(defaultProxySelector.select(httpURI));
    proxies.addAll(defaultProxySelector.select(httpsURI));
    for (Proxy proxy : proxies) {
      if (proxy.type() != Proxy.Type.HTTP) {
        requestorTypes = new Authenticator.RequestorType[]{Authenticator.RequestorType.PROXY};
      }
    }
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
    //ignore
  }
}
```

If needed, I can add `HttpResponseInterceptor` and `HttpRequestInterceptor` instances to the `AbstractHttpClient`.

Comment: I have a question. Can you envisage a situation when a process simultaneously acts as an origin server and a proxy with different sets of user identities while listening on _the same port_ for incoming requests ?

Comment: @oleg Perhaps not. But how would my CredentialsProvider know ?

Comment: It would not, because in normal circumstances it would not need to know. Host and port alone should be sufficient to uniquely identify an HTTP endpoint. This is the reason for CredentialsProvider not differentiating between proxy and origin servers. Essentially the answer to your main question is no: there is no way to reliably determine whether or not the credentials are requested for a proxy.